# Calculating real surface area using Zonal Statistics as Table Tool?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, spatial-analyst, zonal-statistics

I have a slope dataset.  I have a polygon shapefile with territory within the extent of the slope map.  how do I calculate the real surface area of this shapefile using the zonal statistics as table tool to get the sum of pixel values?  I am using ArcInfo 10.1

Comment: Zonal statistics of the slope will not compute the surface area: you need to compute the zonal sum or zonal mean of the secant of the slope.  See [the followup thread](http://gis.stackexchange.com/a/108662/664) for details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able using the 'zonal statistics as table' tool that you mention. There is an option of what 'statistics type' to calculate, select "All" and the last column of the resulting table will be a sum of all pixels within each specified zone. 
[image: zonal statistics as table tool ArcGIS 10.1]

Comment: ok, I have done so.  Many thanks.  Having the sum value, how do I know what the raster cell in square meter is for this extent?

Comment: @user3784813 If you have another question can you research/ask it separately, please?